# How to Make Directories with the Same Parent Name

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, cd, mkdir

**How to Make Directories with the Same Parent Name?**

In my library, I have the following layout:

```
DataFolder
   PATIENT A
          FOLDER1
          FOLDER2
          FOLDER# 
   PATIENT B
          FOLDER1
          FOLDER2
          FOLDER#
```

In each of the Folders I want to Make a **subfolder with the Patient name** like xxPatient A etc...
then within THOSE folders, I want to make two more folders named "TypeX" and "Typez"

How can I do this? This is what I have so far...

```
cd /mnt/d/DataFolder
for i in * 
do
cd ${i}

for j in FOLDER*
do 
cd ${j}

mkdir 


cd ../
done 

cd ../
done
```

This is what I want in the end:

```
DataFolder
   PATIENT A
      FOLDER1
        xxPATIENTA
          TypeX
          TypeZ
      FOLDER2
        xxPATIENTA
          TypeX
          TypeZ
   PATIENT B
      FOLDER1
        xxPATIENTB
          TypeX
          TypeZ
      FOLDER2
        xxPATIENTB
          TypeX
          TypeZ
      FOLDER# 
        xxPATIENTB
          TypeX
          TypeZ
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want. You mentioned you want to create folders named "TypeX" and "Typez". However, your example shows "FOLDER1", "FOLDER2", etc. Are you saying you want to create something ~inside~ FOLDER1, and FOLDER2, and FOLDER3, etc... ?

Comment: I updated the question, thank you PJ Singh

Comment: One more question. Do the directories immediately under DataFolder (i.e. PATIENT A, etc.) already exist, or do you need to create those as well? If so, do the directories named "FOLDER1", "FOLDER2", "FOLDER#" already exist, or do you need to create those?

Comment: Thank you and yes, DataFolder, Patient A, and Folder # all already exist

Comment: Would it suit you to have a "template" folder with all the sub-directories but no foles, and to just copy that folder, renaming it each time?

Comment: If two separate scripts can be used, then that is also helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a structure like this...

```
DataFolder
├── PATIENT A
│   ├── FOLDER1
│   └── FOLDER2
└── PATIENT B
    ├── FOLDER1
    ├── FOLDER2
    └── FOLDER3
```

Use the following bash script...

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");
for patient_name in `ls -1 DataFolder`; do
    echo "Processing ${patient_name}"
    for sub_folder_name in `ls -1 DataFolder/${patient_name}`; do
        echo "    Processing ${sub_folder_name}"
        mkdir -p "DataFolder/${patient_name}/${sub_folder_name}/xx${patient_name}/"{"TypeX","TypeY"}
    done
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

...to create a folder structure like this...

```
DataFolder
├── PATIENT A
│   ├── FOLDER1
│   │   └── xxPATIENT A
│   │       ├── TypeX
│   │       └── TypeY
│   └── FOLDER2
│       └── xxPATIENT A
│           ├── TypeX
│           └── TypeY
└── PATIENT B
    ├── FOLDER1
    │   └── xxPATIENT B
    │       ├── TypeX
    │       └── TypeY
    ├── FOLDER2
    │   └── xxPATIENT B
    │       ├── TypeX
    │       └── TypeY
    └── FOLDER3
        └── xxPATIENT B
            ├── TypeX
            └── TypeY
```

Explanation:

- There are two loops in this script.
- The first loop lists all the existing patient folders (PATIENT A, PATIENT B, etc.) in DataFolder.
- The second loop lists all of the existing folders (FOLDER1, FOLDER2, FOLDER#) within each patient folder.
- The `mkdir` command creates the folder structure you want. It uses the `-p` flag to create *all* parent folders in the supplied path argument.
- At the end of the path argument to the `mkdir` command is `{"TypeX","TypeY"}`. This tells bash that you want to create two folders, named "TypeX" and "TypeY" at the same location.
- Before starting the script, you change the IFS (Internal Field Separator) to *only* break lines on new lines, not spaces. This is important because you have spaces in your file names (for example "PATIENT A"), and you want to loop through each file name, not each word in each file name.
- You also save a copy of the current IFS so you can restore it after the script is finished.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
while IFS=/ read -d '' -r a b c; do
    mkdir -p "$a/$b/$c/xx${b// /}"/Type{X,Y}
done < <(shopt -s failglob; printf %s\\0 DataFolder/*/*)
```

Comment: This would be much more useful if you added an explanation what each part accomplishes.